# redis scan returns not all values. (go-redis)

Tags: redis, go-redis

Redis `SCAN` command with small `COUNT` for large keys, not all keys always returned.

- 10000 keys, 1000 COUNT = return all keys.
- 10000 keys, 10 COUNT = return not all keys.

I want to get all keys for so many keys(100 million), without using commands like `keys`.
What should i do?

```
var keys []string
redis.ForEachMaster(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, master *redis.Client) error {
    iter := master.Scan(ctx, cursor, match, count).Iterator()
    for iter.Next(ctx) {
        keys = append(keys, iter.Val())
    }
    return nil
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as per doc, if u pass count less than 1... the command will return all matches